# PayPal SDK integration in iOS application in live mode

Tags: ios, paypal

I integrate PayPal in my application and using sandbox account to check payment and everything is ok 
Does apple rejected any iOS app, if I use PayPal payment ?? 
and how I turned to live mode ?

Comment: if everything is working fine in sandbox mode then there is no need to worry it will work fine on live version and did not reject by apple.And you can submit your app on app store for live mode.

Comment: i create a fake account in paypal and create my applictaion then Enter your credentials in app delegate 
what shoud i do to turn to live mode ??